Understanding a linear algebra result from a paper
I am reading these notes (https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4315/2020h/Harville-1974.pdf)

I am trying to understand why this identity is true.

Given:
$$ AtA = I $$
$$ G = H^{-1}X(X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1} $$
Prove:
$$ |det(A,G)| = [det\{(A,G)^t(A,G)\}]^{1/2} = \{det(I)\}^{1/2} \{det(G^tG - G^tAI^{-1}A^tG)\}^{1/2} = \{det(X^tX)\}^{-1/2} $$

I tried to analyze the expression $|det(A,G)|$:
$$ |det(A,G)| = [det\{(A,G)^t(A,G)\}]^{1/2} $$
This is because for any square matrix M, $|det(M)| = [det(M^tM)]^{1/2}$.
Then, I tried to expand $(A,G)^t(A,G)$:
$$ (A,G)^t(A,G) = \begin{pmatrix} A^t \\ G^t \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A & G \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A^tA & A^tG \\ G^tA & G^tG \end{pmatrix} $$
Since $A^tA = I$, so:
$$ (A,G)^t(A,G) = \begin{pmatrix} I & A^tG \\ G^tA & G^tG \end{pmatrix} $$
For a 2x2 block matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} P & Q \\ R & S \end{pmatrix}$, where P is invertible, the determinant is given by (Schur Complement):
$$ det\begin{pmatrix} P & Q \\ R & S \end{pmatrix} = det(P) \cdot det(S - RP^{-1}Q) $$
Therefore, the determinant of the above block matrix is:
$$ det\{(A,G)^t(A,G)\} = det(I) \cdot det(G^tG - G^tAI^{-1}A^tG) $$
Raising to the power of half:
$$ [det\{(A,G)^t(A,G)\}]^{1/2} = \{det(I)\}^{1/2} \{det(G^tG - G^tAI^{-1}A^tG)\}^{1/2} $$
For $G^tG$:
$$ G^tG = [(X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1}X^tH^{-1}] [H^{-1}X(X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1}] = (X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1} $$
Therefore:
$$ det(G^tG) = det((X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1}) = [det(X^tH^{-1}X)]^{-1} $$
If $H$ is symmetric and positive definite, we can write $H = LL^t$ where $L$ is lower triangular. Then:
$$ X^tH^{-1}X = X^t(L^{-1})^tL^{-1}X = (L^{-1}X)^t(L^{-1}X) $$
Here is where I am stuck and I do not know how to proceed. Can someone help me continue?

Look at the second term
$$
-G^tAA^tG=-G^tSG=-G^t(I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^t)G.
$$
The first term $-G^tG$ cancels against the term you tried to handle, so there is nothing left to handle. The second term expands and simplifies as
\begin{align}
&G^tX(X^TX)^{-1}X^tG
\\&=(X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1}X^tH^{-1}\,X(X^tX)^{-1}X^t\,H^{-1}X(X^tH^{-1}X)^{-1}
\\&=(X^tX)^{-1},
\end{align}
as claimed.
